# Problema retorno en funcion laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

hasta hora he logrado contear los usuarios hijos de cada padre, es decir con el siguiente metodo logro el siguiente resultado.

```html
  public function reportes(Request $request)
    { 
        $request->user()->authorizeRoles(['admin']);

        $reporuser=usuarios::distinct('usuario_ad')->pluck('usuario_ad');


          foreach($reporuser as $reporuser)

          {

            $conteo=usuarios::where('usuario_ad',$reporuser)->count();
            echo $conteo


          }

        
     }
```

el resultado es 4233, osea que un usuario padre tiene 4 hijos, otro 2, y los dos ultimos padres tienen de a 3 usuarios, el resultado esperado, pero cuando reemplazo echo por return solo me muestra el primer valor, osea 4, y no se por que.

Comment: Como deberías recibir la respuesta: un solo numero `4233`? un array de los números? `array(4, 2, 3, 3)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que al hacer un return estas indicando que salga inmediatamente de la función devolviendo el valor que le indicas. Es decir, ingresas al for la primera vez y le dices salí de la funcion y devolve $conteo que en ese momento tiene solo el valor 4.
Para que funcione como pretendes deberías retornar el valor luego del bucle. Saludos!

**Algo así:**

```
public function reportes(Request $request)
{ 
    $request->user()->authorizeRoles(['admin']);

    $reporuser=usuarios::distinct('usuario_ad')->pluck('usuario_ad');

     $conteo=0;
      foreach($reporuser as $reporuser)
      {
        $conteo= $conteo + usuarios::where('usuario_ad',$reporuser)->count();
      }

    return $conteo;
 }
```

Comment: Gracias frank, con esto me doy cuenta que lo puedo hacer otra forma

Comment: Estuve intentando explicarle esto al OP en sus otras preguntas pero nunca logro entenderlo.